# Iframe emded не загружается на маленьком разрешении

Tags: html, iframe

На сайте используется следующий код:

```
<iframe src="https://path.to/file.pdf" width="100%" height="500" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

В нем загружается .pdf файл. В десктопной версии загружается нормально, но при использовании средств адаптивной верстки в Chrome и при открытии на мобильных устройствах в iframe пусто. Как исправить подобное поведение?

Comment: В мобильных браузерах нет поддержки pdf

Comment: Вставляйте пдфку из гугл драйва, так будет на мобилах отображаться, либо используйте pdf.js